# $L^{p}_{loc}$ as a normed space

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, lebesgue-integral

What norms can we define on $L^p_{\mathrm{loc}}$ ?
or What is the most commonly used norm on $L^p_{\mathrm{loc}}$.
It is tempting to define
 $$\|f\|_{L^p_{\mathrm{loc}}}:=\sup_{K\;\text{is compact}}{\|f\|_{L^{p}(K)}}$$

But this can be infinite for $f\in L^p_{\mathrm{loc}}$.

Comment: A norm should be a map from the normed space $X$ to $\mathbb R^+$. It should not take the value $\infty$ for elements of $X$. But for $f \in L^p_{loc}$ your definition allows this.

Comment: What I am saying is, your construction is not a norm on $L^p_{loc}$. On $L^p$ it coincides with the typical $L^p$ norm, though.

Comment: @ P.Pet . You are right of course. This is a norm on a linear subspace of $L^{p}_{\text{loc}}$.

Comment: I corrected the question thank's to P.Pet 's remark,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no "interesting" or "useful" norm on $L^p_{loc}$. Meaning that there is no norm that induces the standard topology; no norm such that $||f_n||\to0$ if and only if $\int_K|f_n|^p\to0$ for every compact $K$.

Otoh $L^p_{loc}$ *is* metrizable, assuming the underlying space $X$ has an "exhaustion" by  compact sets: If there exists a sequence $(K_n)$ of compact sets such that $K_n\subset K_{n+1}^o$ and $\bigcup K_n=X$ you can define $$d(f,g)=\sum 2^{-n}\frac{(\int_{K_n}|f-g|^p)^{1/p}}{1+(\int_{K_n}|f-g|^p)^{1/p}}$$and then $d(f_n,0)\to0$ if and only if $\int_K|f|^p\to0$ for every compact $K$.

Comment: Another metric is $D(f,g)=\sup\left\{\left(\int_{K_n}|f-g|^p\right)^{1/p} \wedge 1/n: n\in\mathbb N \right\}$ (where $a\wedge b$ is the minimum of two real numbers).